# Azure Log Analytics workspace alert rule giving bad gateway error while disabling alert rule using Azure powershell

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

I am trying to disable Azure alert rule with target resource LogAnalytics workspace using below powershell command,

```
Update-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AlertRuleName -Enabled $false
```

But getting below error:

```
Exception type: Exception, Message: System.Exception: Error in updating Log Alert Rule ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadGateway'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.ScheduledQueryRulesOperations.<UpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bad request error is too board, you could use `Fiddler` to catch the detailed error message.I test in my site and it works well. For more details, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/update-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-3.7.0#code-try-3).

```
Update-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "LogAlertRule1" -Enabled $false
```